# How can I declare a new collection from a package?

Tags: meteor

I'm writing a Meteor package that needs to create a new collection.

`NewCollection = new Mongo.Collection('newcollection');` doesn't work in package code because Mongo isn't available to the package (`Mongo is not defined`).

How can I create a new collection in a Meteor package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [`package.js`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs) file just include the `mongo` package:

```js
Package.onUse(function (api) {
    api.use('mongo');
});
```